# .Net Downloading lots of huge sized documents from my web app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, download, zip

I am looking for a solution to download lots of files possibly huge all at the same time from my web application. It's like a download-all option or extract-all-documents option for my users.
Downloading all as zip file is not always working. definitely it'll take too long and I am not aware of any other solutions, any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Cheers